# Ionic 2 - Store user credentials (local storage vs nav params)

Tags: ionic2

I´m developing an Ionic 2 app. When I make login, I could store user credentials on `SQLStorage`, `LocalStorage` or transfer it as parameter on `NavParam`.

Example:

```
onLogin(){
this.nav.setRoot(MainPageComponent,user);
}
```

vs

```
let storage = new Storage(SqlStorage);
storage.set('name', 'Max');
```

What is the main advantage of storage over passing as parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the main advantage of storage over passing as parameter?

If you use that information just in one page or two, you can send it as parameter. But the problem is that you will probably use the `name` in more than one place (maybe in a *settings* page, or in the *side menu* of the app, and so on), so storing that information somewhere would be a good idea so you can get it back when you need to.

Also, if you get that information in one page, and you want to show it in another one, but those pages are not connected directly in the workflow of your app, you would need to pass it through some other pages just to get it where you want to show it. So again, storing that data seems to be a better approach.

Please notice that if you use SQLStorage or LocalStorage, you should set also an expiration date to force the user to log in again after a given period of time.

Answer (score 1):

`Navparams` is used for transferring the data between pages say, you have to open a particular item's details, you need to click on an Item and the parameters will be sent using `Navprams` to the `itemDescription` page.
You prefer `localstorage.setItem('userId', $userId)`, because storing locally will solve the unwanted sign-in every time you open the app. 
If you store in your local storage, then on every app on load, we can check the existence of the local variable.

```
if(localstorage.getItem('userId')==null){
    this.signin();
}
else{
    this.appOpen();
}
```

This one can help you!